# Git log does not show history before a certain date

Tags: git

In my local Git repository I **cannot see the history (`git log`) before a certain date** (about a month ago) although the history goes back much further (years).

Probably also related: when I do a `git blame` it shows only one author and the wrong author for the whole file.

In the `origin` repository (central repository) the history is fine.

**Does anyone know what the problem could be / know a solution?** For me, this is a new phenomenon and seems to be since I updated my Git version to 2.10 (Windows 10 computer).

Comment: Could you have done a "shallow clone"? If `.git/shallow` exists it is a shallow clone and you must do `git fetch --unshallow` to get the full history.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this was almost the full the solution! The `.git/shallow` file existed (don't know how that happened because it was not initially a shallow clone). I ran `git fetch --unshallow` and the shallow file was gone but the full history was not there yet. When I ran this in addition I had the full history: `git fetch --depth=1000000`. If you want to add that as the answer I will mark it as correct, otherwise I will add it myself later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have done a "shallow clone"? If `.git/shallow` exists it is a shallow clone and you must do `git fetch --unshallow` to get the full history.